# Экспорт функции c# в dll

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dllimport, using

Нужно создать dll файл с функциями, которые сможет прочитать программа на delphi из этого файла.
Для этого создаю библиотеку классов c#, прописал функцию и с помощью `using RGiesecke.DllExport`  использую `[DllExport]`, в итоге беру из папки проекта bin/debug/ свою dll, но программа dllexp не видит никаких функций в данной dll. Что я могу делать не так, подскажите? Код приведен ниже.

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace ReqLibrary
{
    public class Methods
    {
        [DllExport]
        static public void Start(string fam, string im, string ot, string w, string dr, string enp)
         {
           //Код
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620167/12888024

Comment: @aepot, все настолько сложно? Delphy не может подключать в проект обычные dll-ки (как в любом C# проекте)?

Comment: @dgzargo для неуправляемых библиотек должна быть явно указана разрядность процессора, `Any CPU` не подходит, ничего сложного.

Comment: Есть [альтернатива](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com)